# Merging and add records in array

Tags: javascript

Suppose if we have following array.

```
[{ "id": "a01", "key": "k01", "value" : 100},
{ "id": "a02", "key": "k02", "value" : 320},
{ "id": "a02", "key": "k02", "value" : 20},
{ "id": "a02", "key": "k02", "value" : 220},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k01", "value" : 120},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k01",  "value" : 120},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k03",  "value" : 300}]
```

I would like to create new array as following.

```
[{ "id": "a01", "key": "k01", "value" : 100},
{ "id": "a02", "key": "k02", "value" : 560},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k01", "value" : 240},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k03",  "value" : 300}]
```

I would like to merge record and add values which has same ids and keys.
Occurrence could be different.
What will be the easiest way to achieve this?

I tried .filter in the for loop to extract records with same ids and keys,
Able to adds up the result then push it into new array, however I could not skip other records.
Is there way to skip records during the loop?
(e.g. like i+filteredArr.length instead of i++ for loop counter)

Comment: As being an active member for over a year you should know the first step is trying something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let x = [
{ "id": "a01", "key": "k01", "value" : 100},
{ "id": "a02", "key": "k02", "value" : 320},
{ "id": "a02", "key": "k02", "value" : 20},
{ "id": "a02", "key": "k02", "value" : 220},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k01", "value" : 120},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k01",  "value" : 120},
{ "id": "a03", "key": "k03",  "value" : 300}
]

let y = {};
x.forEach((val)=> {
  if(y[val.id + '_' + val.key]) {
    y[val.id + '_' + val.key].value = y[val.id + '_' + val.key].value + val.value;
  }
  else {
    y[val.id + '_' + val.key] = {
      "value": val.value
    }
  }
})

let arr = [];
for(key in y) {
  let id_key = key.split("_")
  arr.push({
    id: id_key[0],
    key: id_key[1],
    value: y[key].value
  });
  
}

console.log(arr);
```